# how to count views in react native flatlist items

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I have a flat list and it contains a list of posts and videos, now I need to count the views for each item, I tried using **viewabilityConfig** and **onViewableItemsChanged** in the flat list and it works fine if I only want to count visible item as a view.

problem is that I had a function written inside **onViewableItemsChanged** for pausing video **right after** user **scrolls** from video.
now I have two functions with different execution times. how can I handle these two functions ?

```
onViewableItemsChanged = (info) => {
    if (this.props.enableView) {
        console.log('item viewed after minimumViewavlitytime 5s: ', info) //done after 5s of view time
    }
    this.pauseVideoFunction(); //done exactly after scrolling
};
    
viewabilityConfig = {
    minimumViewTime:5000,
    waitForInteraction: false,
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i handled it this way:

- removed minimumViewTime from config file
- added this to constructor since its a class component

```js
this.debouncedViewCount = debounce(this.countView, 5000);*
```

- called debouncedViewCount inside `onViewableItemsChanged`

now I have a denounced view counter which runs after 5 second if scroll doesn't move and can pause video right after scrolling

```js
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.debouncedViewCount = debounce(this.countView, 5000); //aaaaaaaaaaa
    }
    countView = (info) => {
        debounce(console.log('Debouced 5s', info), 5000, false)
    }
    
    onVideoExitScreen = (info) => { //todo working on view aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        if (this.props.enableView) {
            this.debouncedViewCount(info);
        }
        pauseVideoFunction();
    };
}
```

```
//inside Flatlist
onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
```